# Relogio em Python não atualiza

Tags: python, gui

Estou tentando criar um relógio em PyGTK. Mas parece que deu algum erro de semântica aqui:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
from datetime import *

def relogio():
    janela = gtk.Window()
    janela.set_title("Relógio digital")

    label = gtk.Label()
    janela.add(label)

    janela.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    janela.show_all()

    while 1:
        label.set_markup("<big>" + str(datetime.now().hour) + ":" + str(datetime.now().minute) + ":" + str(datetime.now().second) + "</big>")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    relogio()
    gtk.mainloop()
```

Poderiam me ajudar a consertar? Vejam que ao rodar o código com o interpretador, a janela simplesmente não aparece!

Comment: Seria o caso de mudar a atualização do relógio para uma outra função chamada por um timer. Da forma que está, o loop infinito não permite o retorno da função relogio(), não chegando nunca ao gtk.mainloop(), o que de qualquer forma atrapalharia o refresh da tela mesmo que ela aparecesse. Além disso, com um loop infinito desses sem nenhum intervalo nem nada, seu relógio vai ser um belo consumidor de CPU...

Comment: Certo... o que faço para consertar, então?

Comment: Bom dia, sempre use titulos referentes ao problema, "O que há de errado", "Ajuda", "Help", "Por favor" não definem nada e não ajudam em nada pra entender o problema, são redundantes, já que quando alguém posta uma duvida aqui é que provavelmente o código não esta mesmo funcionando como esperado. Leve este comentário como uma critica construtiva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que esse código esteja bloqueando tudo em um loop sem fim e sem brecha para nada mais executar:

```
while 1:
    label.set_markup("<big>" + str(datetime.now().hour) + ":" + str(datetime.now().minute) + ":" + str(datetime.now().second) + "</big>")
```

Eu moveria essa segunda linha para outro método e usaria criaria um timer para chamá-la repetidamente. Também converti para uma classe para ficar mais encapsulado:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
from datetime import *

class Relogio():
    def __init__(self):
        janela = gtk.Window()
        janela.set_title("Relógio digital")

        self.label = gtk.Label()
        janela.add(self.label)

        janela.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        janela.show_all()
        gtk.timeout_add(1000, self.atualiza)

    def atualiza(self):
        self.label.set_markup(datetime.now().strftime('<big>%H:%M:%S</big>'))
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    relogio = Relogio()
    gtk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Seria `__initi__` ou `__init__`?

Comment: Consertei. Alterei o código da pergunta sem testar ;)

Comment: Olha, gente... o código atualiza apenas uma vez:

Comment: Bom dia @Gabriel Não entendi seu comentário aqui na resposta do Sergiopereira, você quer dizer que a resposta dele não funciona? Explique melhor.

Comment: Foi mal. Eu estava sem tempo de testar durante a semana e esqueci o `return True` no final de `atualiza`. Consertei agora.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que da uma chance para o **GTK** redesenhar as atualizações no `label` e também criar uma **thread** para obter a hora atual.

Veja como ficou seu código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import threading
import logging
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
from datetime import *

class Relogio():
    def __init__(self):
        janela = gtk.Window()
        janela.set_title("Relógio digital")

        self.label = gtk.Label()
        janela.add(self.label)

        janela.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        janela.show_all()
        gtk.timeout_add(1, self.atualiza) #Mude o timeout para 1

    def atualiza(self):            
        while gtk.events_pending(): #Verifica os eventos pedentes.
            gtk.main_iteration() #Aqui esta fazendo as interações.
            self.label.set_text(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')) #Defini para a metodo set_text.        

if __name__ == '__main__':                
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',)
    relogio = Relogio()
    t1 = threading.Thread(name='Hora', target=relogio.atualiza())
    t1.start()
    gtk.main()
```

Fontes: [Trabalhando com thread](http://zeldani.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/python-usando-o-modulo-threading.html). [Obtendo interações para atualizar o label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018688/gtk-label-not-updated-in-timer-script).